# C#: Why is my background worker thread signaling done when it isn't?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

C#, using VS2010 and I've got something that makes no sense.

At startup my program needs to load several hundred k from text files.  After ensuring the loading code was working fine I threw it in a background thread.  So long as this is run from within the IDE everything's fine but when it's run standalone the thread says it's done when it isn't.  This of course goes boom.

The trigger code:

```
BackgroundWorker Background = new BackgroundWorker();
Background.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(DatabaseLoaded);
Background.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(delegate { Database.Load(); });
Background.RunWorkerAsync();
```

and the stuff that's going boom is in `DatabaseLoaded()`.

I put some messageboxes to trace what's going on:  The first and last lines of the `Load()` method and the first line of `DatabaseLoaded()`.

In the IDE this triggers as I expect:  `Load()` beginning, `Load()` done, `DatabaseLoaded()`.  However, when run standalone I get `Load()` beginning, `DatabaseLoaded()` and then the unhandled exception box (the loader hasn't even gotten to build empty tables, let alone fill them.)

Am I nuts or is Microsoft?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`RunWorkerCompleted` will be invoked in case of an error (such as an unhandled exception in `Database.Load()`). Check the `Error` property of the `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs`.

Comment: That's it.  For some reason it GetExecutingAssembly().Location returned a different path and it wasn't finding everything.

Answer (score 4):

There's probably an exception thrown from `Database.Load()`. `BackgroundWorker` catches any unhandled exception before triggering the `RunWorkerCompleted` event. Check the `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Error` property in `DatabaseLoaded`.

Comment: :-) just two answers posted almost at the same time… Will be interesting to watch whose's going to get more upvotes :-D

Comment: Actually yours was posted 5 minutes later.

Comment: It just refreshed for me and  I think I opened the question after both already posted according to the "answered xxxx ago".

Comment: @gmcalab yeah, I apparently spent a few more minutes in .NET Reflector…